# Remainder in the Wiener-Ikehara theorem

Tags: reference-request, tauberian-theory, wieners-tauberian-theorem

I am looking for a reference for a variant of the Wiener-Ikehara theorem (for Dirichlet series) giving result of the form
$$ \sum_{n\leq X} a(n) = cX^a(\log X)^m + O\big(X(\log X)^{m-1}\big),$$
i.e. with an error term better than $o(1)$. I have looked into Tenenbaum's book (Theorem 7.13) but both the condition and the expression for the error term seem overly complicated. I also looked into Korevaar's book but couldn't find it there either.

All I managed to get is [this article (in french)](https://www.math.nyu.edu/~tschinke/papers/yuri/01zeta/zeta.pdf) where Theorem A.1 in Appendix A gives this type of result under some growth condition. The authors say that this is a well-known theorem but they could not find it in the literature, so I wondered where this might appear.

Comment: @reuns My $L$-series are very nice, basically powers of $\zeta$ up to some holomorphic factor.

Comment: Then what is your precise Dirichlet series ? What do you assume for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n) n^{-s}$ ?

Comment: I have $\sum a(n)n^{-s} = H(s)\zeta(s)^k$ where $H$ is holomorphic and explicit, e.g. $H(s) = \prod_{p|A}(1+p^{-s})$ for some fixed parameter $A$.

Comment: Then $H(s)$ is a finite Dirichlet series so it is enough to look at the partial sums of the coefficients of $\zeta(s)^k$ which is Titchmarsh's chapter "(Dirichlet) divisor problem" (the error term will be much more precise than what you wrote)

Comment: Perhaps you could have a look at the following monograph of T.  Ganelius (1969): "*Tauberian Remainder Theorems**, LNM 232 Springer Verlag. I am not familiar with the book but I stumbled on it while searching references on paricular power series remainder estimates, and it seems relevant for your problem.